# Speeding up analysis on arrays in numpy

Tags: python, performance, numpy, multiprocessing, fft

I have a python code, which imports 4 column txt file with numbers
first three columns are x,y,z coordinate and fourth column is a density at that coordinate.

below is the code that reads, converts to ndarray, Fourier transform that field, calculate the distance from origin (k=(0,0,0)) and a transformed coordinate, and taking average, and plot them.
Thanks to pandas (python library for data analysis) and python FFT, loading 256^3 rows and Fourier transform them are very fast and done in few seconds.

However, transforming the loaded txt to numpy ndarray, calculating the average density (average values of each coordinate), and calculating distance from the origin (k=(0,0,0)) take very long time.

I think the problem is np.around part at the end but I can't figure out the way to optimize it.

I have a resource of 32 core machine.

Could someone teach me how to speed up, make it a multiprocess code, or something like that so that those can be done very quickly? Thanks.

(If you are cosmologist and ever need this code, you may use it but please contact me, if you can. Thanks)

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np

ngridx = 128
ngridy = 128    
ngridz = 128

maxK = max(ngridx,ngridy,ngridz)

#making input file
f = np.zeros((ngridx*ngridy*ngridz,4))

i = 0
for i in np.arange(len(f)):
    f[i][0] = int(i/(ngridy*ngridz))
    f[i][1] = int((i/ngridz))%ngridy
    f[i][2] = int(i%ngridz)
    f[i][3] = np.random.rand(1)
    if i%1000000 ==0:
        print i
#This takes forever
#end making input file

#Thanks to Mike,
a = f[:,3].reshape(ngridx,ngridy,ngridz)

avg =np.sum(f[:,3])/len(f)
a /= avg
p = np.fft.fftn(a)
#This part is much much faster than before (Original Post).

#Keeping track of corresponding wavenumbers (k_x, k_y,k_z) for each element in p
#This is just a convension on fourier transformation so you can ignore this part
kValx = np.fft.fftfreq( ngridx , (1.0 / ngridx ) )
kValy = np.fft.fftfreq( ngridy , (1.0 / ngridy ) )
kValz = np.fft.fftfreq( ngridz , (1.0 / ngridz ) )
kx = np.zeros((ngridx,ngridy,ngridz))
ky = np.zeros((ngridx,ngridy,ngridz))
kz = np.zeros((ngridx,ngridy,ngridz))
rangecolx = np.arange(ngridx)
rangecoly = np.arange(ngridy)
rangecolz = np.arange(ngridz)
for row in np.arange(ngridx):
    for column in np.arange(ngridy):
        for height in np.arange(ngridz):
            kx[row][column][height] = (kValx[row])
            ky[row][column][height] = (kValy[column])
            kz[row][column][height] = (kValz[height])
    if row%10 == 0:
        print row
print 'wavenumber generate complete!'

#Calculating the average powerspectrum in terms of fixed K (Distance from origin to a point in fourier space)
#by taking the spherical shell of thickness 1 and averaging out the values inside it.
#I am sure that this process can be optimised somehow, but I gave up.

qlen = maxK/2 #Nyquist frequency
q = np.zeros(((qlen),4),dtype=complex)
#q is a four column array with length maxK/2.
#q[:,0] is integer wavenumber (K, which is the distance from the origin = sqrt(kx^2+ky^2+kz^2))
#q[:,1] is the sum of square of the fourier transformed value 
#q[:,2] is the sum of the fourier transformed value, 
#and q[:,3] is the total number of samples with K=q[:,0]

for i in  np.arange(len(q)):
    q[i][0] = i
i = 0
for i in np.arange(len(p)):
    for r in np.arange(len(p[0])):
        for s in np.arange(len(p[0,0])):
            K = np.around(np.sqrt(kx[i,r,s]**2+ky[i,r,s]**2+kz[i,r,s]**2))
            if K < qlen:
                q[K][1]=q[K][1]+np.abs(p[i,r,s])**2
                q[K][2]=q[K][2]+p[i,r,s]
                q[K][3]=q[K][3]+1   
    if i%10 ==0:
        print 'i = ',i,' !'
print q
```

Comment: Please try to boil down your code to something shorter which still demonstrates the slowness.  What you have there is way longer than a typical successful SO question's code.  Also, please provide a short program which produces valid input, such as by using `np.random`.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you could be more specific about which parts are slow.  I think I can figure out the parts you mean, but you should point to them clearly, to make sure nobody spends too much time thinking about the wrong parts of your code.

Comment: `b = a[1:]` should get rid of the 1st loop. `a[tuple(f[:,:2])]=f[:,3]` might work for the second; `np.sum(f[:,3])` the third.

Comment: Thanks, I just edited and updated to the latest code with taking account of suggestions from John and Mike.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Numpy can typically do things hundreds of time faster than plain python, with very little extra effort (and sometimes will even automatically use multiple cores with no work from you).  You just have to know the right ways to write your code.  Just to name the first things I think of:

- Think about your approach — simplify it and make sure it's right before coding it
- Learn to use numpy's indexing
- Don't copy data if possible
- Try to avoid loops at all costs
- Use numpy's built-in functions
- Work on whole arrays (or large pieces of arrays), rather than individual elements at a time
- Profile your code to find the slow spots
- Use [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/), especially for loops you can't avoid or that numpy can't help with

## Your approach

One mistake that I think we all make is trying to write *only* in code, even when we're still trying to figure out what the code should do — basically, speaking a language we don't really understand very well, which isn't really descriptive and has a very limited number of words.  I find it better to first outline my approach in plain English as a series of steps.  This lets me see clearly, and in my own words, exactly what I want the code to do.  So it's easy to get an overview and think about what's going on, but also easy to rewrite if I realize that something needs to be reworked.

In fact, I write the steps as comments on separate lines in a code file.  Once I'm happy with the approach, I start writing the code itself between those comments.  This leaves me with a well structured and properly commented code.

In the particular example of the original code in the OP, the entire `f` array probably doesn't need to exist.  If you were just writing out the procedure in plain English, I think you would see this, and be able to change your approach easily *in plain English* before you code it up.  As it stands, so much of the code relies on `f` that it would require a complete rewrite to change it.

## Indexing

Plain python is often very slow at things that a computer should be great at.  One example is with indexing, so a line like

```
a[f[i,0]][f[i,1]][f[i,2]]=f[i,3]
```

makes me very suspicious.  Is this the one you're referring to when you say "transforming the loaded txt to numpy ndarray" takes a very long time?  That wouldn't surprise me, because each time python sees `a[f[i,0]]`, it has to index `f` first, making sure that `i` is an integer, and you haven't run off the edge of `f`; then it has to make sure `f[i,0]` is an integer, and you haven't run off the edge of `a`.  Then it has to repeat this two more times before it even knows which element you want to set.

One improvement is to use `a[f[i,0],f[i,1],f[i,2]]`, because numpy is faster with that kind of indexing.

But I assume your data are actually in some kind of order.  For example, does `f[i,2]` loop from 0 to 256, then `f[i,1]` increments by 1, and f[i,2] starts over at 0?  If so, all you actually need to do is to say something like

```
a = f[:,3].reshape(ngridx,ngridy,ngridz)
```

That's a ridiculously fast operation, taking a fraction of a millisecond.  The shape might be wrong, so you might have to change the order of the arguments, are do something with transposes, but the basic idea is definitely there.  You can read about it in [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html).

More specifically, if I understand the code correctly, those first three sections of code could be completely replaced by just

```
a = np.random.rand(ngridx,ngridy,ngridz)
```

That is, `f` doesn't need to exist at all, as far as I can see.

## Copying data is bad

You don't need to copy everything, and when you do need to copy an array (or part of an array), you should let numpy do it for you.  For example, instead of your `Firstdel` function, just use `a[1:]`:

```
def Firstdel(a):
    return a[1:]
```

This doesn't copy the data at all; the thing it returns just ignores the fact that another number is stored in RAM immediately before it.  Or, if you really need to make a copy of the data (which you don't just for plotting) use this:

```
def Firstdel(a):
    return numpy.copy(a[1:])
```

But typically, you can just use "slices" of numpy arrays, rather than copying them.  Read about it [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing).

However, also be aware that if you just take a slice (and no copying happens), that means that if you write to the slice, the original array will also be written to.

## Loops

Loops are also notorious time wasters — specifically when those loops are in the python code, rather than some C code.  In fact, I would argue that the whole point of numpy is to replace loops that you would write in python with loops that they've written for you in C.

First of all, `while` is not common in python for simple loops.  So instead of

```
while i < len(f):
    # do stuff
    i = i+1
```

you should probably use

```
for i in range(len(f)):
    # do stuff
```

But this is just an issue of style and readability.  For speed, you need to get rid of as many loops as you can — especially nested loops.  To set `kx`, `ky`, and `kz`, this code is about 10 times faster than the nested loops for the parameters in the OP, but scales as N instead of N^3 (where `N=ngridx*ngridy*ngridz`):

```
for row in range(ngridx):
    kx[row,:,:] = kValx[row]
for column in range(ngridy):
    ky[:,column,:] = kValy[column]
for height in range(ngridz):
    kz[:,:,height] = kValz[height]
```

Slicing can also be useful for setting values, because the loop goes inside of numpy.  Instead of this code

```
i = 0
while i < len(q):
    q[i][0] = i
    i = i + 1
```

just use

```
q[:,0] = np.arange(len(q))
```

Here, I'm just setting a "slice" of `q` equal to another array.

The nested loops following that loop can also be sped up, but they'll be a bit more complicated.

But you also want to avoid loops wherever possible.  Which brings us to...

## Use built-in numpy functions

Again, the main reason numpy exists is to translate these slow python loops into fast `C` code (that we don't need to know exists).  So there are a lot of functions that do things you want to do already built in to numpy.

Instead of

```
while i < len(f):
    masstot = masstot + f[i,3]
    i = i+1
```

you should use something like

```
masstot = np.sum(f[:,3])
```

It's simpler to read, but also likely to be *way* faster, because numpy has direct access to that data in the computer's memory, and can use fast `C` functions to find the sum, rather than using slow python functions.  (Again, you don't need to know anything about the `C` functions; they'll just do the work.)

## Work on whole arrays (or slices)

One common mistake is to use numpy functions, but *still* do the loops themselves.  There's a prime example of that in this code:

```
for i in np.arange(len(p)):
    for r in np.arange(len(p[0])):
        for s in np.arange(len(p[0,0])):
            K = np.around(np.sqrt(kx[i,r,s]**2+ky[i,r,s]**2+kz[i,r,s]**2))
```

Instead of that big nested loop calculating values of `K` each time through the loop, just make `K` an array with the appropriate values:

```
K = np.around(np.sqrt(kx**2+ky**2+kz**2))
```

`K` will be the same size and shape as `kx`, `ky`, and `kz`.  Then, you can use [advanced indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) to set the values of `q`.  This is how you could do that last section:

```
# Again, we get rid of nested loops, to get a large improvement in speed and scaling
K = np.around(np.sqrt(kx**2+ky**2+kz**2)).astype(int)
for i in range(qlen):
    p_i = p[K==i]  # This will be just the elements of p where K==i
    q[i,0] = i
    q[i,1] = np.sum(np.abs(p_i)**2)
    q[i,2] = np.sum(p_i)
    q[i,3] = len(p_i)
print q
```

Putting these tips together, I get about a factor of 70 improvement over the code currently in your question.  If it's still too slow, you can use a profiler to find the slow parts.  And if you still can't improve them, it might be worth trying numba, which compiles the code as you need it, to run almost as fast as equivalent C code.

Comment: Thank You so much Mike, for your help. I am re writing and minimizing the code so that problematic part is clearer. Basically, reducing Loops and using build-in numpy functions made the code way faster. However, still could not figure out the last indexing part.

Comment: I have updated the post accounting in all the suggestions you have put in on this answer. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: What does "run off the edge" mean in this context?

Comment: You're welcome!  I think you may have missed a few other optimizations that I added into my question after I first posted it -- including one just now, which cuts about a minute off the time, depending on ngrid, etc.  Just remember: you really do want to remove as many python loops as possible, and use slicing as much as possible.  Get good at slicing, that's my advice.

Comment: @cxrodgers Out-of-bounds indexing of the array.  Python checks that indices are in bounds mercilessly, and that's one of the notorious slowdowns in high-performance computing.

Comment: OK @TomohiroHashizume, one las edit to show you how to do that last part, which is the slowest part of your code.

Comment: @Mike and everyone, thank you so much  for answering my question. It got much much much faster than my original crappy code. thank you so much. Just one thing , for me `q[i,3] = sum(indices)` didn't work because of the error `TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars` so I used `q[i,3] = (indices==1).sum()` instead. Thank you so much again!!!

Comment: @Tom, ```numpy``` (as well as Python) treat ```True``` as one and ```False``` as zero so ```indices.sum()``` should work.  The ```TypeError``` is because the Python ```sum``` function can't deal with the array - when working with ```numpy``` arrays its best to stick with ```numpy``` functions.

Comment: Hm.  That's strange.  I guess you did something different from what I did, but I can't figure out what it might have been.  Or maybe you're using an older version of numpy.  I've cleaned up my version of your code (which I already had in an [ipython notebook](http://ipython.org/notebook.html)), and you can view it online [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/moble/820999c8901968bbcd29).

Comment: Thank you for the cleaned up version! yes, I also liked the wwii's version for `kx`, `ky`, and `kz` so I used that.
change sum() to `np.sum()` solved the problem! Thank you so much for nice and neat explanations. I love python + scipy packages so much and now even more. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Might as well speed up the *input file* creation as well:

```
size = ngridx*ngridy*ngridz
f = np.zeros((size,4))
a = np.arange(size)
f[:, 0] = np.floor_divide(a, ngridy*ngridz)
f[:, 1] = np.fmod(np.floor_divide(a, ngridz), ngridy)
f[:, 2] = np.fmod(a, ngridz)
f[:, 3] = np.random.rand(size)
```

To make `kx`, `ky`, and `kz`, you can get rid of the loops using [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html#broadcasting):

```
kx += kValx[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]
ky += kValy[np.newaxis, :, np.newaxis]
kz += kValz[np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :]
```

Comment: You don't have to use `np.floor_divide` and `np.fmod`; you can just use `//` and `%` as usual.  Since `a` is a numpy array, it knows what to do.

Comment: Thanks, that's way nicer than what I did.

Comment: @Mike,  is there a disadvantage to using the ```ufunc```s?

Comment: I think they're precisely the same -- one calls the other.  It's just a notational nicety that makes the code easier to read IMO.

Comment: wow! I though using broadcasting + newaxis is very very clever. Thank you so much for everyone who helped me!

Comment: Psst.  @Tom.  It's considered polite to upvote helpful answers, even (or especially) if you don't accept them as the solution.

Comment: sorry, my reputation was under 15 until now :) now I've voted upwards. Thanks!